# Factorizable vector

Tags: tensor-products

How I will be able to prove that:

If $|\psi\rangle$ is not factorizable (entagled with two qbits) then the unitary operator $U_1\otimes U_2$ apply on $|\psi\rangle$ is not factorizable?

*factorizable is when a $|\psi\rangle$ vector can be express than $|\psi\rangle = (a|0\rangle + b|1\rangle)\otimes(c|0\rangle + d|1\rangle)$

Comment: I assume $|\psi\rangle\in V\otimes W$ and $U_1\in{\rm GL}(V)$, $U_2\in{\rm GL}(W)$?

Comment: not, because if this happens then $|\psi\rangle$ is factorizable

Comment: What? (Are you saying that every element of $V\otimes W$ is factorizable? That's wrong.)

Comment: mmm, then I will be able to say: Any vector $|\psi\rangle$ belong to set with the form $V\otimes W$?

Comment: A vector belongs to a vector space. What vector space does $|\psi\rangle$ belong to?

Comment: @anon thank by your replys, the vector space is $\mathbb{C}^4$ and the unitary operator $U_1\otimes U_2 \in \mathbb{C}^{4\times 4}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're familiar with the concept of a vector space: a collection of elements called vectors that forms an additive abelian group, with multiplication by 'scalars' coming from some field, in many cases the scalar field is the reals $\bf R$ or the complex numbers $\bf C$. Any complex vector space of finite dimension $n$ is isomorphic to ${\bf C}^n$, the space of $n$-tuples with components from $\bf C$.

The tensor product is a way to combine two vector spaces (it can be more general than this, of course, but that is outside the present scope of discussion). If $V$ and $W$ are complex vector spaces, then the tensor product $V\otimes W$ is a vector space spanned by symbols of the form $v\otimes w$ with $v\in V$ and $w\in W$, subject to the following linearity relations for all $v,v_1,v_2\in V$, $w,w_1,w_2\in W$, $\lambda\in\bf C$:

$$\begin{cases}(v_1+v_2)\otimes w=v_1\otimes w+v_2\otimes w \\ v\otimes (w_1+w_2)=v\otimes w_1+v\otimes w_2 \\ (\lambda v)\otimes w=\lambda(v\otimes w)=v\otimes (\lambda w).\end{cases}$$

It is noteworthy that not every vector in $V\otimes W$ can be written as "$v\otimes w$"; these are called pure tensors, or in your terms, factorizable. But every vector in $V\otimes W$ can be written as a linear combination of pure tensors. In particular, any pair of bases ${\cal B}_V$ and ${\cal B}_W$ for $V$ and $W$ respectively induce a basis ${\cal B}_{V\otimes W}=\{r\otimes s:r\in{\cal B}_V, s\in{\cal B}_W\}$ for the tensor product $V\otimes W$.

Suppose $V$ to be the $2$-dimensional free vector space over $\bf C$ spanned by the symbols $|0\rangle,|1\rangle$, which we may interpret as pure states of a physical system. $V$ is itself interpreted as a space of possible states for a qubit. Explicitly, ever vector in $V$ is of the form $\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle$ for some $\alpha,\beta\in\bf C$.

To represent two qubits, we look at the tensor product $V^{\otimes 2}=V\otimes V$. Since $\{|0\rangle,|1\rangle\}$ is a basis for just $V$, a basis for $V^{\otimes 2}$ is $\{|0\rangle\otimes|0\rangle,|0\rangle\otimes|1\rangle,|1\rangle\otimes|0\rangle,|1\rangle\otimes|1\rangle\}$, so every vector looks like

$$\alpha\,|0\rangle\otimes|0\rangle+\beta\,|0\rangle\otimes|1\rangle+\gamma\,|1\rangle\otimes|0\rangle+\delta\,|1\rangle\otimes|1\rangle.$$

The vector space is isomorphic to ${\bf C}^4$, but I wouldn't call it that because ${\bf C}^4$ is defined to be a space spanned by $4$-tuples, things that look like $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta)$, whereas $V^{\otimes 2}$ is spanned by tensors and comes with additional information about how vector can be represented in more than one way via to the linearity relations.

Your problem arises in a bit more generality, but for convenience sake we stick to $V\otimes W$ rather than something $V_1\otimes V_2\otimes \cdots \otimes V_l$. Let $A\in{\rm GL}(V)$ and $B\in{\rm GL}(W)$ be any invertible linear maps on $V$ and $W$ respectively. I claim that there is a (unique) linear map $V^{\otimes 2}\to V^{\otimes 2}$ with the property that $v\otimes w$ is always sent to $A v\otimes B w$. To define a linear map it suffices to define where the elements of a given basis should be sent. Pick any bases ${\cal B}_V$ and ${\cal B}_W$, and define $A\otimes B$ to be the linear map that sends $r\otimes s$ to $Ar\otimes Bs$ specifically for $r\in{\cal B}_V$ and $s\in{\cal B}_W$. Then for any two elements $v\in V$ and $w\in W$ we can write $v=\sum_{r\in{\cal B}_V} a_rr$ and $w=\sum_{s\in{\cal B}_W}b_s s$, so

$$\begin{array}{ll} (A\otimes B)(v\otimes w) & =(A\otimes B)\left[\left(\sum_ra_rr\right)\otimes\left(\sum_sb_ss\right)\right] \\ & = (A\otimes B)\left[\sum_{r,s}a_rb_s(r\otimes s)\right] \\ & = \sum_{r,s} a_r b_s (A\otimes B)(r\otimes s) \\ & = \sum_{r,s} a_r b_s (Ar\otimes Bs) \\ & = \left(\sum_r a_r Ar\right)\otimes \left(\sum_s b_s Bs\right) \\ & = \left(A\sum_ra_rr\right)\otimes \left(B\sum_sb_ss\right) \\ & = Av\otimes Bw.\end{array}$$

This is a very nice property, it makes the world a simpler place.

The adjoint of $U_1\otimes U_2$ has a simple representation: $(U_1\otimes U_2)^*=U_1^*\otimes U_2^*$. To show this, one needs to check that $U_1^*\otimes U_2^*$ satisfies the definition for being an adjoint of $U_1\otimes U_2$; note that the inner product on $V\otimes W$ for these purposes is assumed to be induced from the inner products on $V$ and $W$. Towards this end we need only check the defining condition for the pure tensors, since pure tensors span the space, and this is fairly immediate (it amounts pretty much to juggling around parentheses). This is a nice exercise in the way of initiation to tensors, and I leave it at that.

I also leave the following as exercises (consider everything over $\bf C$):

- ${\rm Id}_V\otimes {\rm Id}_W={\rm Id}_{V\otimes W}$;
- $(A\otimes B)(C\otimes D)=AC\otimes BD$ for any $A,C\in{\rm GL}(V)$, $B,D\in{\rm GL}(W)$;
- $(A\otimes B)^{-1}=A^{-1}\otimes B^{-1}$;
- if $A\otimes B=C\otimes D$, then $A=C$ and $B=D$.

Thus, if $U_1\otimes U_2$ is unitary, it means that

$${\rm Id}_V\otimes {\rm Id}_W=(U_1\otimes U_2)(U_1\otimes U_2)^*=(U_1\otimes U_2)(U_1^*\otimes U_2^*)=U_1U_1^*\otimes U_2U_2^* $$

hence $U_1U_1^*={\rm Id}_V$ and $U_2U_2^*={\rm Id}_W$, i.e. $U_1$ and $U_2$ are unitary and in particular invertible maps. After all of these preliminaries I will finally address your problem.

We wish to show in $V\otimes W$ that, for any $A\in{\rm GL}(V)$ and $B\in{\rm GL}(W)$,

$$|\psi\rangle~{\rm factorizable}\iff (A\otimes B)|\psi\rangle~{\rm factorizable}.$$

First we show $\Rightarrow$. Suppose $|\psi\rangle=|\phi_1\rangle\otimes|\phi_2\rangle$ for some $|\phi_1\rangle\in V$ and $|\phi_2\rangle\in W$. Then by the previous work we know that $(A\otimes B)|\psi\rangle=(A\otimes B)(|\phi_1\rangle\otimes|\phi_2\rangle)=(A|\phi_1\rangle)\otimes(B|\phi_2\rangle)$, which is clearly factorizable (it's already 'factored'!). For the converse, the $\Leftarrow$ direction, we can actually *apply* the first direction. That is, if $(A\otimes B)|\psi\rangle$ is factorizable, then

$$|\psi\rangle=(A\otimes B)^{-1}(A\otimes B)|\psi\rangle=(A^{-1}\otimes B^{-1})\big((A\otimes B)|\psi\rangle\big)$$

is factorizable, and this is the statement of the reverse direction.